# Is there anyway on livecd with persistance to write the original file system on the pendrive?

Tags: boot, usb, mount, live-usb, filesystem

I couldn't find my pendrive in "this computer"section when i boot a live system from it.But later i found it mounted at /cdrom
Unluckily for me, I have to modify a word doc on the pendrive(from /cdrom),but everything including the file on /cdrom is r/o
Is there any way for me to access my pendrive with R/W provelliges?

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details; but a ISO when written to *pen-drive* is written to be either RO or RO with a RW components (usually COW achieving the persistence), but you've not given any OS & release details which is a start, plus how it was initially written to your media.

Comment: A "LiveCD with persistence" does not grant R/W access to the system files. "Persistence" refers to an additional partition that can be mounted R/W and written to. `sudo lsblk` will show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Modify a File on Persistent USB

This depends on how you made the thumb drive. Systems like Etcher, dd, mkusb, Disks, Startup Disk Creator, etc, clone a read only ISO9660 partition from the ISO file. Everything in this partition is read only.

On a Persistent USB data in normally saved to a folder in Home. When booted from the drive it should be accessible in `/home/ubuntu/Documents` etc.

If you just dropped the document onto the drive while it was plugged into another system it may be in `/cdrom`.

Rufus and UNetbootin extract the ISO file to either a FAT32 or NTFS partition. The `/cdrom` folder is read only when booted from the Live USB, but it is accessible when booted from another Linux or Windows drive.

If you added the Doc while booted from the USB, your Word doc will be located in a file or partition named either "casper-rw", "writable" (or "home-rw" if a custom USB).

Unetbootin, YUMI, Ventoy and Universal USB Creator use a Persistence file that can be mounted and accessed RW from another running Ubuntu disk.

Rufus and mkusb use a Persistent partition that can be accessed RW from the live USB or from another Linux disk.

It can not be read from a Windows system without a special app.

To get at your Word document in a mounted Persistent file or partition. You should see a file system similar to "this computer". Open the folder named `/upper/home/ubuntu/Documents`, etc.  You should find your file in documents"